# Dividing complex shapes into contiguous sub-shapes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, geometry, shapes

I have a 3D shape loaded into MATLAB as a 3D matrix. The matrix is fairly large, e.g. 250x250x250. The shape is defined within the matrix by numbers >0 but <=1, so all positive numbers in the matrix are "shape", and all zeros are "non-shape". The shape is contiguous. A simplified (8x8) example of one plane of such a shape is shown in below:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1 .5 .1 .2  1  0
0  0  0  0  0 .3  0  0
0  0 .2 .3  1  1  1  1
0  0  0 .8  1  0  0  0
0 .2 .1  1  0  1  0  0
0 .1 .9 .9 .9  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I need to split this shape into 2 sub-shapes where the sum of values of the two sub-shapes is roughly equal, and where the two sub-shapes are contiguous. So a valid division could be [N.B. zeros replaced by '.' for visual clarity]:

```
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  B  B  B  B  B  .
.  .  .  .  .  B  .  .
.  .  A  A  B  B  B  B
.  .  .  A  A  .  .  .
.  A  A  A  .  A  .  .
.  A  A  A  A  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

But the following division would be invalid because not all of the values in sub-shape B can be directly joined up with each other.

```
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  B  B  B  A  A  .
.  .  .  .  .  A  .  .
.  .  B  B  A  A  A  A
.  .  .  B  A  .  .  .
.  B  B  B  .  A  .  .
.  B  B  B  B  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

My real-world example is in 3 dimensions and much larger. Any ideas how I could divide my shape into 2 contiguous sub-shapes. By extension, how can I divide it into 3 contiguous sub-shapes if I wanted to, again where the sum of values in the sub-shapes is approximately equal?